# Where can I find the Python type hints for builtin classes and ABCs?

Tags: python, python-typing

Where can I find the Python type hints for builtin classes and ABCs? For example, where can I find the type hint for `MutableSet[T].__isub__`, which I imagine is something like

```
def __isub__(self, other: Set[T]) -> None:
    ...
```

Comment: Are you referring to type hints as given by a specific python IDE (editor), and if so, which?

Comment: The docs has the best info for type hints [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.MutableSet)

Comment: @MattB. I'm looking for all the method type hints—not just the generic type names.

Comment: @InonPeled No, I'm looking for the type hints that are part of the Python language or part of mypy (I'm not sure which).

Comment: The stubs most IDEs use are collected in the [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/), which is maintained along with the CPython and MyPy codebase. Builtins are defined [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for `MutableSet.__isub__`, I followed the imports to types.pyi, which defines the method as following:

```
def __isub__(self, s: AbstractSet[Any]) -> MutableSet[_T]: ...
```

This actually appears as part of [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), which Pycharm installs by default, so it's apparently not an integral part of CPython.
I assume you can do the same for other ABC's. I could not, however, find similar type hints for built-in types such as list.

Comment: Nice job!  Do you have a link?

Comment: (The type hints for list are probably under `Sequence`)